# Mysql fulltext search query

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a firstname and a surname field in my mysql table. And i dont know in which order a user enters the firstname and surname in ONE field.
My fulltext index is on PERSONEN_VNAME and PERSONEN_NAME
So he can write "tester a" or "a tester".

I got these two persons:

1. Surname: TESTER, Firstname: Andrea
2. Surname: Tester, Firstname: A

I tried this query:

```
SELECT PERSONEN_ID,PERSONEN_VNAME, PERSONEN_NAME FROM
 PATIENT WHERE match(personen_name,personen_vname) against
('+tester* +a* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

The query returns me just TESTER Andrea but not Tester A.

Why!?

EDIT: sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21f29/1

Comment: added fiddle to original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:-

```
SELECT PERSONEN_ID,PERSONEN_VNAME, PERSONEN_NAME FROM
 PATIENT WHERE match(personen_name,personen_vname) against
('+tester* +a% ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21f29/2)

Comment: Thanks! What is the ? doing? Because i dont find it in the Documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: Use % instead. It is a substitute for zero or more characters.

Comment: but if you search for tester andr, nothing is found. why? :/